# Python Matplotlib: Graphinc conic inequalities

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to graph a conic section in Matplotlib that is filled in. Ideally, something like this:

[image: something like this:]

Right now I have this code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2

mpl.rcParams['lines.color'] = 'k'
mpl.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'] =mpl.cycler('color', ['k'])

x = np.linspace(-9, 9, 400)
y = np.linspace(-5, 5, 400)
x, y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

def axes():
    plt.axhline(0, alpha=.1)
    plt.axvline(0, alpha=.1)

a, b, c, d, e, f = 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, -2
axes()
plt.contour(x, y,(a*x**2 + b*x*y + c*y**2 + d*x + e*y + f), [0], colors='k')

plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')
plt.show()
```

and it looks like this:

[image: and it looks like this:]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy solution is to use a filled contour (`contourf`) instead of a line contour (`contour`).

```
a, b, c, d, e, f = 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, -2
plt.contourf(x, y,(a*x**2 + b*x*y + c*y**2 + d*x + e*y + f), [f, 0], colors='k')
```

Complete example

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(-9, 9, 400)
y = np.linspace(-5, 5, 400)
x, y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

plt.axhline(0, alpha=.1, c="k")
plt.axvline(0, alpha=.1, c="k")

a, b, c, d, e, f = 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, -2

plt.contourf(x, y,(a*x**2 + b*x*y + c*y**2 + d*x + e*y + f), [f, 0], colors='k')

plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')
plt.show()
```

[image]